# Going through categories that have different names for each category and product name

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data of a website called: https://www.powermaxed.com/.

Its directory structure is not very consistent, and I don't know what to do next.

Here is the code that I use for scraping:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'powermaxed'
    start_urls = ['https://www.powermaxed.com/']

    def parse_product(self, response):

        yield {
            'product_title': response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@id="content"]//h1/text()').extract_first()
            'product_price_w/_tax': response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@id="content"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@class="product-buy-wrapper"]//ul[@class="list-unstyled pp"]//li//h2//span[@id="formated_price"]/text()').extract_first()
            'product_price_w/o_tax': response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@id="content"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@class="product-buy-wrapper"]//ul[@class="list-unstyled pp"]//li//span[@id="formated_tax"]/text()').extract_first()
            'product_desc': response.xpath('//div[@id="product-tabs"]//div[@class="tab-content"]//div[@id="tab-description"]//p/text()').extract_first()
            'product_uses': response.xpath('//div[@id="product-tabs"]//div[@class="tab-content"]//div[@id="tab-description"]//ul//li/text()').extract()
        }
```

The extracted data would be the product infomation.

I need is to access all product pages from all directories on this website
and extract the information I've put in the code.

I scrapy shelled the website so I've set what data I want to extract on the spider.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply scrape all the pages and return a product if there's one:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'powermaxed.com'
    start_urls = ['https://www.powermaxed.com/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_product'),
    )

    def parse_product(self, response):

        product_title = response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@id="content"]//h1/text()').extract_first()

        if product_title:
            yield {
                'product_title': product_title,
                'product_price_w/_tax': response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@id="content"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@class="product-buy-wrapper"]//ul[@class="list-unstyled pp"]//li//h2//span[@id="formated_price"]/text()').extract_first(),
                'product_price_w/o_tax': response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@id="content"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@class="product-buy-wrapper"]//ul[@class="list-unstyled pp"]//li//span[@id="formated_tax"]/text()').extract_first(),
                'product_desc': response.xpath('//div[@id="product-tabs"]//div[@class="tab-content"]//div[@id="tab-description"]//p/text()').extract_first(),
                'product_uses': response.xpath('//div[@id="product-tabs"]//div[@class="tab-content"]//div[@id="tab-description"]//ul//li/text()').extract(),
            }
```

Comment: Guillaume, I would like to thank you for that once again, however the results from that seems to be really all over the place, it is getting the path as well as **some** of the products. It's a start and I really thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add more details to your questions? What kind of help do you need?

Get all main categories from homepage, for example, like `nav#supermenu ul > li > a[href]:not(.tllhome)` and scrape all the products from there. Iterate by left filter block `div.panel-category a` if needed.

Also you can try to scrape categories from sitemap (https://www.powermaxed.com/sitemap.xml) and get all the products from these pages.